# Hidden and static filter on all repository methods for an entity

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

**Disclaimer**: Please do not suggest database-model redesigns / database model concept flaws. This question is about the case described, there is no way to change that case apprently.

---

Assuming i hava a table `fruits`, with `name`, `color` and `type` as fields
This means, all apples have the `type=apple`, all oranges have `type=orange` and so on.

Now creating a JPA entity/model called `Apple` with those 3 fields mapped and the `Table=fruits`, i want to create a `AppleRepository` where the argument `type` is statically set to `apple` and not visible to the outer consumers.

So i do **not** want to offer

`AppleRepository.findByTypeAndNameContains` with requiring the caller to now to set `type` to `apple`

but rather just

`AppleRepository.findByNameContains` while type is statically set to `apple`.

(With the same method i would then chose to `Orange` and the `OrangeRepository` using `type=orange`)

I understand i could use `@Query` to write a custom query where type is just statically included and only mapping the dynamic parameters... but

Question:
Is there a elegant way to implement that without using `@Query`?

Comment: Yes, just une inheritance with the single table strategy. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance

Comment: Thank you. The inheritance is not really the question. I understand i can minimize mapping dupulication this way and all this. But i do not understand how this would help with my core question on how to set `type` statically for each of the models then? Readin your article, i could not gain that detail - any clues on this follow up?

Comment: sorry, got it `DTYPE` if no other name is give. Thank you! Do you dare writing it down as an answer so i can accept it? I guess it would need a little more detail then the link, but other then that, is sounds like the perfect solution!

Comment: It's not "my article". It's the official Hibernate documentation. The single table inheritance consists in storing all the entities in a hierarchy inside a single table, and distinguishing them using a disscriminator column. I.e. exactly what you're trying to achieve. Did you at least click on the link leadig to https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-single-table? It explains things in quite some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is the principle behind the "singe table" inheritance strategy. It consists in storing all the entities in a hierarchy inside a single table, and distinguishing them using a discriminator column (i.e. your type column).

See [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-single-table) for details